# Save to database on change, angular and node js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I'm converting an MS Access database to a webapp. I'm using Angular JS, Node JS with the express framework and MySQL as database.

In ms access you don't have any edit/save features. When you edit something, the database changes instantly. I like this. Feels smooth. So I want to have this the same way in the web app. My question is. Will there be any problems with this approach in my webbapp?

This is a piece of my node js code which updates the database with a restcall:

```
/*
 Post /api/products/ HTTP/1.1
 */
exports.editProduct = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  var post  = [{title_en: req.body.title_en},req.params.id];
  if (connection) {
    connection.query("UPDATE products SET ?  WHERE id = ?",  post, function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.contentType('application/json');
      res.write(JSON.stringify(rows));
      res.end();
    });
  }
};
```

And on the client side I use the a the $resource object

```
       $scope.save = function(){
         $scope.product.$save(function(){
           console.log('Save successfull);
         });
       };
```

And in the view. I simply have inputs with ng-change:

```
<input ng-model="product.title_en" ng-change="save()".
```

Will this work good in production mode with a couple hundred users? Is the chances of blocking/crashing etc?

Comment: The only thing I see is if (err) throw err; if there is an error the server crash so change it with a json response with a 500 status. By the way express has a build-in way to output json http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I see is if (err) throw err; 
if there is an error the server crash so change it with a json response with a 500 status. 
By the way express has a build-in way to output json
It's better off to validate title_en and id

```
exports.editProduct = function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body);
      var post  = [{title_en: req.body.title_en},req.params.id];
      if (connection) {
        connection.query("UPDATE products SET ?  WHERE id = ?",  post, function(err, rows, fields) {
          if (err) {
              return res.json(500,{ error: 'Cannot update the product' });
          }
          res.json(200,rows);
        });
      }
```

an other thing try to  use [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) instead of resource it's a lot of fun :)
        };

Comment: And there is no problem if 50 people at the same time using this restcall as they are typing in inputboxes?

Comment: It's a mysql issue not a node problem so Use transactions